How is the author and commit message of a squashed merge commit determined?
I'm trying to wrap my head around who should be the author/committer and what the commit message would be in specific git scenarios. I'll use the below example repo to illustrate my question.

Assume we are running git merge --squash --ff-only from main, so that commits C, D, and E will be squashed into 1 commit, placed onto main, and then the head of main will be fast forwarded to the new squashed commit.


ALSO, the authors of each commit are

commit C - thing1
commit D - thing2
commit E - thing3


A -- B (main)
      \
       C -- D -- E (feature_branch)

after merging (assume the feature branch was closed after merging)
A -- B -- F' (main)

note: F' is commits C, D, and E squashed together
My question is: who is the author of commit F' and what would the commit message be?
I'm assuming that whatever user actually runs the command would become the committer of the new squashed commit - is this right?

A merge performed with the --squash option only updates the working directory and the index, it does not create a merge commit.

Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit, move the HEAD, or record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD

Therefore, since you would have to manually create a commit, the author would be composed with the name and email specified in your user.name and user.email variables. While, the commit message would be whatever you would enter during the commit.

A merge command with --squash option will left you with local changes in your working copy which you can then commit yourself :
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---squash
So the author of this new commit will actually be the user running the merge command, and the commit message will be set manually.
